Contraction of a vector in the exterior algebra
Let $L$ be a vector space and $x\in L$. My textbook defines the following operator:
$$i_x: \Lambda^k(L^*) \rightarrow \Lambda^{k-1}(L^*) \\ i_x(\alpha)(x_1,...,x_{k-1})=\alpha(x,...,x_{k-1})$$
Or in coordinate form with Einstein convention:
$$(i_x\alpha)_{j_1...j_{k+1}}=x^i\alpha_{ij_1...j_{k+1}}$$
Then we are given the following property. Suppose $\alpha\in\Lambda^p(L^*)$ and $\beta\in\Lambda^q(L^*)$. Then:
$$i_x(\alpha\wedge\beta)=(i_x\alpha)\wedge\beta+(-1)^p\alpha\wedge(i_x\beta)$$
How do you derive that property?
The furthest I can get to is: $$i_x((\alpha\wedge\beta)_{i_1...i_pi_{p+1}...i_{p+q}}e^{i_1}\wedge...\wedge e^{i_{p+q}})=\frac{1}{p!q!}\sum_{\sigma \in S_n}(-1)^{[\sigma]}x^{i_{\sigma(1)}}(\alpha\otimes\beta)_{i_{\sigma(1)}...i_{\sigma(p+q)}}e^{i_{\sigma(2)}}\otimes...\otimes e^{i_{\sigma(p+q)}}$$
From here I should somehow split the sum in two parts but I'm not exactly sure what reasoning would lead me to the given expression for the property.

What have you tried?

@NicholasTodoroff I just edited to include my try

First, you should have $i_x(\alpha\wedge\beta)(x_1,\dots,x_{p+q-1})$. Second, I would recommend that you use multilinearity to fix a basis for $L$ and take $x$ to be a basis vector and $\alpha$ and $\beta$ to be (dual) basis forms.

You do not need to expand $\alpha$ in a basis like this. I would suggest assuming $\alpha$ & $\beta$ are simple (equivalent to Ted Shifrin's suggestion) and considering induction on $p$. Even though the $p=0$ case is easiest, you will need to use $p=1$ as the base case. For the inductive step with $p+1$, you can write $\alpha = \alpha_0\wedge\alpha'$ for $\alpha_0\in L^*$ and $\alpha'$ a simple $p$-form.

I'm not sure exactly how to prove it that way. Can you write an answer?

We will proceed by induction on $p$. It suffices to assume $\alpha$ is simple and then extend by linearity.
$p=0$ is trivial.
When $p=1$, we compute
$$\begin{aligned}
  i_x(\alpha\wedge\beta)(y_1,\dotsc,y_q)
  &= (\alpha\wedge\beta)(x,y_1,\dotsc,y_q)
\\&= \alpha(x)\beta(y_1,\dotsb,y_q) + \frac1{q!}\sum_{i=1}^q(-1)^{i}\sum_{\sigma\in S_q}\alpha(y_{\sigma(1)})\beta(y_{\sigma(2)},\dotsc,y_{\sigma(i-1)},x,y_{\sigma(i)},y_{\sigma(i+1)},\dotsc,y_{\sigma(q)})
\\&= \alpha(x)\beta(y_1,\dotsb,y_q) - \frac1{q!}\sum_{i=1}^q\sum_{\sigma\in S_q}\alpha(y_{\sigma(1)})\beta(x,y_{\sigma(2)},\dotsc,y_{\sigma(q)})
\\&= i_x(\alpha)\beta(y_1,\dotsb,y_q) - \frac1{(q-1)!}\sum_{\sigma\in S_q}\alpha(y_{\sigma(1)})i_x(\beta)(y_{\sigma(2)},\dotsc,y_{\sigma(i-1)},y_{\sigma(i+1)},\dotsc,y_{\sigma(q)})
\\&= [i_x(\alpha)\wedge\beta](y_1,\dotsb,y_q) -[\alpha\wedge i_x(\beta)](y_1,\dotsc,y_q)
\end{aligned}$$
as desired. In the second term the intent is for $x$ to be placed in the $i^{\mathrm{th}}$ slot of $\beta$.
Now we assume the result for $p$ and prove it for $p+1$. Because $\alpha$ is simple we can write $\alpha = \alpha_0\wedge\alpha'$ for $\alpha_0\in L^*$ and $\alpha'$ a $p$-form. Then, also using the $p=1$ case as necessary, we compute
$$\begin{aligned}
  i_x(\alpha_0\wedge\alpha'\wedge\beta)
  &= i_x(\alpha_0)\wedge\alpha'\wedge\beta - \alpha_0\wedge i_x(\alpha'\wedge\beta)
\\&= i_x(\alpha_0)\wedge\alpha'\wedge\beta - \alpha_0\wedge[i_x(\alpha')\wedge\beta + (-1)^p\alpha'\wedge i_x(\beta')]
\\&= [i_x(\alpha_0)\wedge\alpha' - \alpha_0\wedge i_x(\alpha')]\wedge\beta + (-1)^{p+1}\alpha\wedge i_x(\beta)
\\&= i_x(\alpha)\wedge\beta + (-1)^{p+1}\alpha\wedge i_x(\beta) .
\end{aligned}$$
